# Principled BSDF incorrect roughness scaling?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I watched a [video from Blender Guru](https://youtu.be/V3wghbZ-Vh4?t=2478) (link with time where he mentions it) where Andrew was forging basically a "fake" principled bsdf to get a material. He showed that the glossy BSDF lost gloss too quickly and he countered it by raising the texture's data to the second power. 
My question is, is this still the case with Principled BSDF so we have to counter it, or is it corrected?

Comment: Please add a concrete example of the issue.

Comment: Sorry, it just got me thinking, not in the middle of a project :/ Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Principled BSDF uses squared roughness internally to better match other software and tools. The glossy BSDF does not, hence why it was necessary to square the roughness with a math node on older PBR node groups.

Comment: Thanks for the input :D now when I encounter the shader I won't have to start guessing whether I'm using the correct setup - or worse, forget about it altogether.